# trying to Img fit 100% of div but prevent resizing

Tags: html, css, image

Does anyone knows if its possible to skretch an Image to fit 100% of a div but to stay that big if you resize your browser? I need to be in a  tag and not as background.

html

```
<div id="first">
   <img src="" alt=""/>
<div>
```

css

```
#first img{
 max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean 100% of the width, the height, or both?

Comment: I mean 100% of the initial div and 100% of the initial hight. As if you specified a fix layout with (for example) width:400px and height:300px. When you resize the browser it will not change

Comment: What determines the width of `div#first`? If it depends on the initial size of the browser, then you will need some JavaScript to save the initial browser width and then use that width to set the width of the browser.  In addition, is the width of `div#first` to change with resizing the browser?  You need to provide more context otherwise your question is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

```
#first{
 width:100%;
}
#first img{
 width:inherit;
}
```